# Raphaeljs Substring Text attributes

Tags: javascript, raphael

I was wondering if it's possible to change the attributes of a substring of the text object in Raphael.  For example, I want to bold the word wizard in the following string "The magical wizard ruled the world!" in a raphael text object.  I have looked at using the Raphael.print() method and I need some of the attributes from text for other portions of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Fonts are set at the element level, much like in regular html.  In order to apply a separate font or style to a specific word, you would need to break your text into separate elements.

```
var start = paper.text(20, 20, "The magical ");
start.attr({ "text-anchor": "start" });
var startBox = start.getBBox();
var bold = paper.text(startBox.width + startBox.x, 20, "wizard ");
bold.attr({ "text-anchor": "start", "font-weight": "bold" });
var boldBox = bold.getBBox();
var end = paper.text(boldBox.width + boldBox.x, 20, "ruled the world!");
end.attr({ "text-anchor": "start" });
```

Answer (score 2):

A problem with the solution by gilly3 is that the x-coordinate of the elements is absolute. When changing the text, for example `bold.attr({"text":"sorcerer"})`, the elements will overlap.

An alternative solution is to compose a text element out of custom `tspan` elements with relative positioning. This is also a bit cleaner from an object model perspective. However, it does require some direct manipulation of the text element. Code:

```
var content = paper.text(20, 20, "The magical").attr({ "text-anchor": "start" });

var txt1=Raphael._g.doc.createTextNode(" wizard ");
var txt2=Raphael._g.doc.createTextNode("ruled the world!");

var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var ts1 = Raphael._g.doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "tspan");
var ts2 = Raphael._g.doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "tspan");

ts1.setAttribute("font-weight","bold");
ts1.appendChild(txt1);
ts2.appendChild(txt2);

content.node.appendChild(ts1);
content.node.appendChild(ts2);

content.node.children[1].textContent=" sorcerer ";
```

Disclaimer: Raphael can change relative positioning of tspans when altering `x,y,dx,dy` of the parent element, even though svg itself can handle this. A transform string can be used instead. Example:

```
content.node.setAttribute("x",500); //works
content.attr({"x":500});  //undesired result
content.transform("t100");   //works
```