# Raphael JS: how to change the color of certain letters within a text-element?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have the following code:

```
        var set = paper.set();
        var text = paper.text(0, 0, 'bla1 bla2' ).attr({ fill: 'blue'});
        set.push(text);
```

How can I change the color of the 'bla2' to green now?

I've already tried to split the string into two text-elements and assign the coordinates of the 'bla1'+ width of the 'bla1' to the second one. It didn't work since I coundn't find out the width of 'bla1'. The second problem with this solution is that I might want to change the font-size of 'bla1 bla2' which will automatically change the width of 'bla1' and distort the position of 'bla2'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the only way that I can think of is to split the string. To get the width use element.getBBox() http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881609/raphaeljs-substring-text-attributes

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517191/raphael-changing-the-letter-color-of-text-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="canvas"></div>​
```

**JS:**

```
var text = "this is some colored text";
var paper = Raphael('canvas', '100%', document.documentElement.clientHeight/2 );
var colors = ["#ffc000", "#1d1d1d", "#e81c6e", "#7c7c7c", "#00aff2"];
var letterSpace = 5;
var xPos = 10;
var yPos = 10;

textNodes = text.split(' ');

for( var i=0; i < textNodes.length; ++i) {       
    var textColor = colors[i];
    var textNode = paper.text( xPos , yPos , textNodes[i]);
        textNode.attr({
            'text-anchor': 'start',
            'font-size' : 12,
            'fill' : textColor
        });
    xPos = xPos + textNode.getBBox().width + letterSpace;
}
​
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/zsS7L/