# How to insert tspan into text-element via javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raphael JS: how to change the color of certain letters within a text-element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942269/raphael-js-how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-letters-within-a-text-element)

Is it somehow possible? Maybe with Raphael js?

My initial question was this one: [Raphael JS: how to change the color of certain letters within a text-element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942269/raphael-js-how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-letters-within-a-text-element)

But nobody yet answered it. I came up with the idea of inserting the strings into tspan so I can separately change their colour.

Comment: My initial question was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942269/raphael-js-how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-letters-within-a-text-element But nobody yet answered it. I came up with the idea of inserting the strings into tspan so I can separately change their colour.